# Declare list field and the constructor in a user defined class in C#

Tags: c#, list, class, constructor, field

So i am learning C# using the "Murach's C# 2015" textbook. In chapter 13 page 411, there is a this code:

```
public class ProductList
{
    private List<Product> products;

    public ProductList()
    {
        products = new List<Product>();
    }
```

So the first line "public class ProductList" declares a class

The second line "private List products;" declares a class variable (ie: "Field")... which in this case is a list... I don't understand this? All I have learned so far is that a list is initialized like this:

```
private List<Product> products = new List<Product>();
```

Can anyone explain this to me? Is this just how it is always done for a list? Or is this short hand? Are there other ways to go about it?

I understand that the next part of the code is a constructor, that is:

```
    public ProductList()
    {
        products = new List<Product>();
    }
```

And I see the "new" key word here that I am used to seeing for a list.

Comment: Your example (that declares and initialize the List) is effectively the same ad declaring the member then initializing it in the constructor. All initialization code that's outside of constructors is gathered together and run before any of the constructors run (a class may have many constructors, an instance gets constructed by one of them). In short, don't worry about it - your thinking was right

Comment: Declaring an object variable and creating an instance for that variable *are two different things*. One informs the compiler and the other prepares it for use.  We often lump them together for convenience, but they are different operations.   Your first code block simply does it in two steps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
private List<Product> products;
```

This declares the field. I.e. tells the compiler that the class contains a field of this type. It will be assigned the default value for the type (i.e. null in this case) unless something more is done.

```
private List<Product> products = new List<Product>();
```

This is a combined declaration and initialization. It does same as the above, but also assignes the field with a newly constructed object. In your case the examples are equivalent. But consider

```
public ProductList(int capacity)
{
    products = new List<Product>(capacity);
}
```

Here we must split declaration and initialization since we need some parameter for the initalization.

Comment: Thank you!! So recently, I was looking at page 387 of "Murach's C# 2015" textbook (chapter 12). It had "private List<Product> products = null;"... So you are saying that is the same as "private List<Product> products;" Basically... just short hand... I had googled this "=null" and found it was very controversial... many people have the opinion that you should never set it =null and instead use "private List<Product> products = new List<Product>();" to make an empty list instead of a null list.

Comment: yes. Initializing it to null is redundant since it is the default behavior, but might be done to show that it is done intentionally. But I would agree that nulls should be avoided as far as possible. After the constructor has completed the object should be fully usable, and this should include assigning all fields.